# Automatically creating next and previous type pages using glob

Tags: php, navigation, glob, slice

Trying to make it so that the glob function displays only the first 10 results (text files from a folder) and then automatically the next 10 with a next button.

Currently, I used array_slice to display only the first 10, but I'm not sure how to automate the process.

```
foreach(array_slice(glob("*.txt"),0,9) as $filename) {
   include($filename); }
```

Oh and while I'm at it, if possible, display something like "displaying 1-10" and last/first links. I could probably figure that out myself after I get past the first obstacle, so don't bother with this unless it's a super easy solution.

Comment: Please start with a basic PHP tutorial. Learn about GET parameters. Oh and while you are at it, if possible, understand what include() does.

Comment: @Jan agreed.  You probably wan to use `file_get_contents()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to accomplish is called pagination. From your example, you can dynamically choose which ten you're viewing by setting a variable that determines what number (file) to start at.

Example:

```
<?php
$start = isset( $_GET['start']) ? intval( $_GET['start']) : 0;

$glob_result = glob("*.txt");
$num_results = count( $glob_result);

// Check to make sure the $start value makes sense
if( $start > $num_results)
{ 
    $start = 0;
}

foreach( array_slice( $glob_result, $start, 9) as $filename) 
{
     include( $filename); // Warning!
}
```

If you only want to do increments of 10, you can add a check to make sure `$start` is divisible by 10, something like this after `$start` is retrieved from the `$_GET` array:

```
$start = ( $start % 10 == 0) ? $start : 0;
```

Now, for links, all you need to do is output `<a>` tags that have the start parameter set correctly. You will have to do some logic to calculate the next and previous values correctly, but here is a simple example:

```
$new_start = $start + 10;
echo '<a href="page.php?start=' . $new_start . '">Next</a>';
```

**Edit:** As the comments above suggest, you probably do not want to `include()` these files, as `include()` will attempt to interpret these files as PHP scripts. If you just need to get the contents of the text files, use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents) instead.